# $.get is not working in my server

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

The following code is working when I run with visual studio:

```
$.get('@Url.Content("Content/templates/new_story.htm")', function (tr) {
    $("#table_body").append(tr.replace(/#story/g, storyNumber));
});
```

But, when I publish in IIS 7.5, the new HTML is not loaded into `#table_body`.

Why?

Comment: Wrong URL? Just guessing

Comment: Can you navigate to the path manually? Do you get any console errors?

Comment: @JanDvorak cannot be wrong URL because works perfectly when I run with visual studio.

Comment: @musefan yes, I can. Any console errors.

Comment: Did you check the network tab? Is the request correct? Is the response correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this when I publish to a virtual directory.  I think what you'll want to do is add a tilda to your URL:

```
$.get('@Url.Content("~/Content/templates/new_story.htm")', function (tr) {
    $("#table_body").append(tr.replace(/#story/g, storyNumber));
});
```