# $.get callback not firing when GETting html from iis 7.5

Tags: jquery, html, callback, get, iis-7.5

I've looked at this [$.get is not working in my server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529783/get-is-not-working-in-my-server) and am pretty sure I have to do something special to make the callback fire.

Problem is: I don't know what that is.

This

```
$.get('myFile.html', function(data) {
    alert('duh');
});
```

downloads `myFile.html` but never fires the callback.  Why?  What do I need to do to make the callback fire?

**Chrome->Developer tools->Network**

Under `XHR`, the `GET` shows `Status` `200`.  I can even see the html source in `Response` and the rendered html in `Preview`.

**$.ajaxError()**

This fires.

**'https://mysite.com/myFile.html'**

Same result as without the absolute path: the `GET` shows `Status` `200`.  I can even see the html source in `Response` and the rendered html in `Preview`.

**$.ajaxError() `thrownError`**

`alert`s `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.

Comment: How are you verifying that myFile.html is retrieved successfully? It sounds like you're actually getting an error code in return.

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: Set an [.ajaxError](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) handler and see if it gets called. Seeing the html returned doesn't necessarily mean there isn't an error. It could be the browser is rejecting it as cross-domain.

Comment: I hope it isn't as simple as using `con` instead of `com`?  Like you did in your link.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy: So what's getting passed to the `.ajaxError` handler? That should help you identify the problem. Look at the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$.get('myFile.html', '', function(data) {
  alert('duh');
}, 'html');
```

jQuery should be able to figure out your short-hand (that the 2nd parameter is not a string), but try this anyway.  Adding in data and HTML parameters won't hurt.

You can also try

```
$.get("myFile.html")
    .done(function(data) { alert("Data Loaded: " + data); })
    .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
    .always(function() { alert("finished"); });
```

And see what comes up.

Comment: Do you happen to know why this is happening?  This doesn't happen on my personal Apache2 (not surprisingly).

Comment: umm... why what is happening -- not working on one server but working on another?  Sounds like a cross-domain issue to me.

Comment: No, it's same domain.  I was just comparing msft to lamp.  I run into far more strange issues like this with msft products than lamp.